# Gmail as client for O365

Tags: gmail, office-365

How do I configure a personal Gmail account to act as the client for my company provided O365 email account?  Would it simply be a matter of setting up SMTP / IMAP, or is it more complicated that that (or even possible)?

Comment: Thanks pnuts.  I don't mind setting up a completely separate gmail account.  Basically, I don't want to use outlook, owa, or anything else to read and sort my email -- just gmail.  In essence, I want gmail to function as a client, where 0365 is the email server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible using POP3 (incoming) and SMTP (outgoing). Gmail cannot act as an IMAP client AFAIK.

Gmail can retrieve up to 5 POP3 accounts and [Office 365 would seem to support POP3](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/settings-for-pop-and-imap-access-for-office-365-for-business-or-microsoft-exchange-accounts-HA102908389.aspx). And you can configure Gmail to send email as your O365 email address, using your O365 SMTP server. From the above link, these settings would seem to be:

```
POP3  outlook.office365.com  995  SSL
SMTP  smtp.office365.com     587  TLS
```

However, possible caveats with this approach:

- You cannot control how often Gmail checks your POP3 account. Gmail decides for you. If  the frequency of your email increases, then Gmail is likely to check more often. You can manually perform a refresh every now and again if you wish. (As an example, I check 3 POP3 accounts using Gmail and it is currently reporting that they were checked 21, 5 and 47 minutes ago respectively.)
- Microsoft recommends Exchange ActiveSync: (although I don't know what exactly you would be missing out on?)

> Although you can connect to your account using POP3 or IMAP4, we recommend that you connect to your account using Exchange ActiveSync because Exchange ActiveSync supports more features than POP3 and IMAP4.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I appreciate the answer.

Comment: I also solved my issue about not being able to edit/move my Gmails on my outlook client by reconnecting to the Gmail account with POP/IMAP manual set up instead of the default Google Account set up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**To add your Office 365 account to Gmail:**

- Click on the 'Settings' icon (a gear in the top right corner).
- Click 'See all settings'.
- Go to the “Accounts and Import” tab.
- Click the 'Add a mail account' link in the 'Check mail from other accounts' section.

**To get your POP and SMTP mail settings, sign in to Outlook for Office 365 at outlook.office.com**

- Click on the 'Settings' icon (a gear in the top right corner).
- Click 'View all Outlook settings'.
- Click 'Sync email'.
- Check that 'Let devices and apps use POP' is checked.

You can see your POP and SMTP settings on that page.

**Office 365 now enforces Multi Factor Authentication by default, you need to turn that off to be able to access your mailbox in Gmail:**

- Log in to `portal.azure.com` with your Office 365 account credentials.
- Click the 'View' button under 'Manage Azure Active Directory'.
- Click 'Properties' in the left-hand menu.
- Click 'Manage Security defaults' at the bottom of the page.
- Set 'Enable Security defaults' to 'No'.

Instructions with screenshots [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults).

That will allow you to access your messages with POP.

**You also need to enable SMTP authentication to be able to send messages, which again is disabled by default.**

- Open the Microsoft 365 admin center at admin.microsoft.com
- Go to Users > Active users in the left-hand menu.
- Click on the user, and in the flyout that appears, click Mail.
- In the Email apps section, click Manage email apps.
- Tick the checkbox for 'Authenticated SMTP'.
- When you're finished, click Save changes.

Instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission).